# Repeat a view in Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have the following design:

[image: Form design]

How should I proceed? Add a `NSScrollView` with the first element, which contains a couple of `NSTextField`s and an `NSImage` and then repeat in the code? What type of repeater should I use? And... is `NSScrollView` able to handle this type of design?

Is it possible to use NSTableView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably have a custom NSView class that contains the date labels on the left, a NSImage that toggles between two states (selected or not) and the request label on the right. You can lay it out either in code or in a .nib and instantiate it that way respectively.

When you create the superview create four of the new subclasses and put them in the appropriate places.

Only use scroll view if you think that you'll have so many options that you will need to scroll.